# Shopify Webhook HMAC Validation With Flask

Tags: python, flask, shopify, webhooks, hmac

I'm trying to verify that the Webhook received is coming from Shopify. They have [this](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/manage-webhooks#verifying-webhooks) doc, but it doesn't work (getting type errors).

Here's what I have so far. It produces no errors, but the `verify_webhook` function always returns false.

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

SECRET = '...'


def verify_webhook(data, hmac_header):    
    digest = hmac.new(SECRET.encode('utf-8'), data, hashlib.sha256).digest()
    genHmac = base64.b64encode(digest)

    return hmac.compare_digest(genHmac, hmac_header.encode('utf-8'))


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello_world(request):
    print('Received Webhook...')

    data = request.get_data()
    hmac_header = request.headers.get('X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256')
    verified = verify_webhook(data, hmac_header)
    
    if not verified:
        return 'Integrity of request compromised...', 401
    
    print('Verified request...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

SECRET = '...'


def verify_webhook(data, hmac_header):    
    digest = hmac.new(SECRET.encode('utf-8'), data, hashlib.sha256).digest()
    genHmac = base64.b64encode(digest)

    return hmac.compare_digest(genHmac, hmac_header.encode('utf-8'))


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello_world(request):
    print('Received Webhook...')

    data = request.data # NOT request.get_data() !!!!!
    hmac_header = request.headers.get('X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256')
    verified = verify_webhook(data, hmac_header)
    
    if not verified:
        return 'Integrity of request compromised...', 401
    
    print('Verified request...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Issue was in the `data = request.get_data()` line.